# Passing an object to element attribute in Polymer 2

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-2.x

I am playing with Polymer 2.0, and I don't understand how to pass an object as an element attribute.

Here's my code:

```
<dom-module id="notes-app">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        display: block;
      }
    </style>
  <button on-click="loadNotes">Get the notes</button>
  <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[notes]]" as="note">
     <note recipe='JSON.stringify(note)'></note>
  </template>
</template>
<script>
  class NotesApp extends Polymer.Element {
    static get is() { return 'notes-app'; }
    static get properties() {
      return {
        notes: {
          type: Array,
          value: []
        }
      };
    }
    loadNotes() {
      this.notes = [
        {"desc":"desc1", "author":"auth1", "type":"type1"},
        {"desc":"desc2", "author":"auth2", "type":"type2"},
        {"desc":"desc3", "author":"auth3", "type":"type3"}
      ];
    }
  }
  window.customElements.define(NotesApp.is, NotesApp);
</script>
</dom-module>
```

`simple-note` is the element who has a property of type `Object`:

```
<dom-module id="note">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        display: block;
      }
    </style>
    <div>
      <fieldset>
        <label>description</label>{{note.desc}}<br>
        <label>author</label>{{note.author}}<br>
        <label>type</label>{{note.type}}
      </fieldset>
    </div>
  </template>
  <script>
    class SimpleNote extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() { return 'simple-note' }
      static get properties() {
        return {
          note: {
            type: Object,
            value:  {},
            notify: true
          }
        };
      }
    }
    customElements.define(SimpleNote.is, SimpleNote);
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

As you can see I want `note-app` to display all the objects in its `notes` property by passing an object representing a note to every `simple-note` elements (don't known if it is the right way to make elements interact each other). I want it to happen when I press the `notes-app` button. How can I pass an object to an element attribute in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're trying to pass the variable as an `object`, you should use property bindings instead of attribute bindings (which only supports strings).

- [Polymer data bindings](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding#anatomy-of-a-data-binding) require curly or square brackets (`{{twoWayBinding}}` or `[[oneWayBinding]]`). For example, to set the `foo` property of the `<x-child>` element to the value of `note`, the template would look something like this:

  ```
  <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[notes]]" as="note">
    <x-child foo="[[note]]">
  </template>
  ```
- Given that `SimpleNote.is` equals `"simple-note"`, I assume your usage of `<note>` and `<dom-module id="note">` were only typos in your question. They should be set to `simple-note`, as the element name [must start with a lowercase ASCII letter and must contain a dash](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements#register-element).
- It looks like you're binding a `recipe` property, but `<simple-note>` declares a `note` property (and no `recipe`) and binds to `note` sub-properties in its template. I assume `recipe` is another typo.

[working demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/NaOYEr?editors=1000)

Comment: My bad. I'll check my example and update my question ASAP. Can't see your code example <template... /template>, could you fix that?